# Play a video on startup then run specific application

Tags: boot, video

I'm currently in the process of building a Magic Mirror for my partners 21st birthday, powered by a Pi.

Currently, the Pi boots the Magic Mirror application upon start up. However, I'd also like to have a video of length 90 seconds to play before the application starts up. Sort of like an instructional video on how to use the mirror. As soon as the video finishes, I'd like the Magic Mirror application to start. Is this something that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify command that runs magic mirror to make it something like this:

```
omxplayer /home/pi/video.mp4; magic_mirror_command_here
```

It will play the video and after it ends it will run second command (`magic_mirror_command_here` in my example)